# Finding $k$ such that $a$ is a real root $x^5-x^3+x-2=0$ with $[a^6]=3k$. ($[x]$ denotes the Greatest Integer function.)

Tags: quintics

> If $a$ is a real root of the equation $x^5-x^3+x-2=0$ such that $[a^6]=3k$. Find $k$.
>
> Here, $[x]$ denotes the Greatest Integer function.

My try:

First I plugged in $1$ in the equation. I got $-1$, which is close to $0$ so the root must be near 1. Then I plugged in $1.1$, I got $-0.62049$. The sign didn't change, so it must be greater than $1.1$. Then I plugged in $1.2$ and I got $-0.03968$ which is very close to $0$ but the sign still didn’t change. So, now I plugged in $1.3$ and I got $0.81593$. The sign did change, but it got farther away from $0$, so the root must be very close to $1.2$. So I assumed $a=1.21$, and with this I got $k=1$.

I was fortunate that this was the correct answer, but I highly doubt this is the correct way to solve this problem. Please tell me if there is any other efficient and correct way of doing this.

Comment: Yup its the greatest integer function

Comment: Note that $x^5-x^3+x-2=(x^3 + x^2 - x - 2)(x^2 - x + 1)$. So the tag "quintic" equations reduces to square and cube. The quadratic polynomial has no real root. So ....

Comment: How did you factorize it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde. What is interesting to notice is that the sixth power of the real root of the cubic is the real solution of the cubic $x^3+6 x^2-7 x-64=0$ (which is $3.07011$)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. How??